# clearcase to perforce : how to branch?

Tags: version-control, migration, perforce, clearcase

We are migrating from `clearcase` to `perforce` and I have question on branching.

In `clearcase` once I branch (say `my_branch`) out I can keep committing incremental changes to a file (say `xyz.cpp`) without being concerned about the `main`.

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
element * .../my_branch/LATEST
element * /main/LATEST -mkbranch my_branch
```

I can keep checking out and checking in `xyz.cpp` as many times as I want into `my_branch`. Suppose I made 23 checkins and I feel the 21st checkin is the one that needs to go into the `main`, I can get the 21st checkin using `ct get` and merge it to `main`.

I can do this for any number of files (say `xyz2.cpp`, `xyz3.cpp` ...) in this branch in `clearcase`. I am not sure how to do this in `perforce`.

How do I replicate this process in `perforce`? I see `p4 submit` but it goes into `main`. Basically I want to keep saving the incremental changes and also retrieve them as needed for any number of files before merging them to `main`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use much the same process but of course the mechanics are different.

**Step 1: Make your new branch**

Let's say that you have a main branch in Perforce located at `//depot/project/main`.  (That path is in Perforce depot syntax.  I can add a link to the relevant docs if you need it.)

I'll define a branch map to capture the information about how the main branch and my new branch relate to one another.

`p4 branch my_branch`

In the branch map I will add this view:

`//depot/project/main/... //depot/project/my_branch/...`

Now I will create the branch:

`p4 populate -b my_branch`

**Step 2: Use the new branch**

I'll create a workspace that contains both branches.  I won't go into all the details but I need a workspace view that looks something like this:

`//depot/project/main/... //my_ws/main/...`

`//depot/project/my_branch/... //my_ws/my_branch/...`

Now I'll populate the workspace:

`p4 sync`

Note that I'll have a copy of both branches in my workspace.  Now I'll check out and make changes on my_branch:

`p4 edit my_branch/foo.c`

`p4 submit -d "my_branch changes`

I can make as many changes on `my_branch` as I need.

**Step 3: merge to main**

Ok, now I'm ready to merge `my_branch` to `main`.  If I want to merge everything I run:

`p4 integ -r -b my_branch`

If I want to just merge a single file:

`p4 integ -r -b my_branch //depot/project/main/foo.c`

Note that I specify the target file.

If I want to just merge a specific revision of a single file:

`p4 integ -r -b my_branch //depot/project/main/foo.c#21`

Comment: Great! +1. Those were the missing commands around branch missing in my answer.

Comment: @p4-randall Thank you. Your answer was very clear and provides a simple model to visualize branching and merging in perforce.

Comment: @p4-randall Typing in `p4 populate -b my_branch` results in `Unknown command.  Try 'p4 help' for info.` Any command to work around this?

Comment: <code>p4 populate</code> is a relatively new command and might not be available in your version.  If not then substitute <code>p4 integ -b my_branch</code> followed by <code>p4 submit</code>.

Comment: @p4-randall Thank you. In step 2 you mention ``I'll create a workspace that contains both branches''. Can you please provide a link which explains the need for this. I thought it should sufficient to map the `my_branch` to the `my_ws`. Why do we need to map `main` to `my_ws`?

Answer (score 1):

The closest from [`cleartool get`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_get.htm) would be [`p4 sync`](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/sync.html)

```
 p4 sync file.c#4
```

> Copy the fourth revision of file.c to the client workspace.
>   If the file is already open in the client workspace, or if the latest revision of the file exists in the client workspace, it is not copied.

After that [`p4 submit`](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/submit.html#1050861) remains an obvious choice, but all files in the changelist are submitted to the depot, and files open for edit, add, and branch are closed.

Comment: Thank you. But how do I `submit` the changes to `file.c` locally to a branch instead of submitting to `main`?